# How can I bind datasourse of bootstrap typeahead in my backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a backbone view. I want to set datasource of bootstrap typeahead from server in every change occur in the search text field. How can I do this??  This is my Search view

```
window.SearchByChoiceView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.model = new SearchByChoiceModel();
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    $(this.el).empty().html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},

});


window.SearchByChoiceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

initialize: function () {     
},

defaults: {
    id: 1,
    SearchKeyword: "",
    "tags": new Array()

}
});
```

And this is my search field:

```
 <input type="text"  required placeholder="search" class="input-span3" id="SearchKeyword" title= "Search Keyword" name="SearchKeyword" value="<%= SearchKeyword %>" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4">
```

Please anyone help. I am a begginer with backbone. May be it is easy but it is very hard to handle for me. I have tried a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this:

```
$( '.typeahead' ).typeahead( {
    source : typeAhead.people.pluck( 'name' )
  } );
});
```

Where "typeAhead.people" is your collection instance.  In your case

```
myApp.myCollection.pluck( 'SearchKeyword' )
```

JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/upigej/1/edit